# How to add search filter drop down in admin block form in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, adminform

Here is my admin field code

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'topic_id',
            'select',
            array(
                'name' => 'topic_id',
                'label' => __('Select Topic '),
                'title' => __('topic '),
                'values'=> $topic_data,
                /*'required' => true,*/
            )
        );
```

> How can i make this field as search values from $topic_data array
>
> like see below screen shoot the drop down have so meany values so i
> will search specific value and select it

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you have dropdwon in form and you want to make it search in grid?

Comment: no not like that but that drop down content so meany values so i will search from that select the value..

Comment: Do you mean you want to do filter the grid same like product type etc attribute work?

Comment: see my quotation i edit it